# React hooks - indexed callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

`useCallback` is useful for memoizing functions to be passed to sub-components, but what if you're rendering those sub-components in a loop? e.g.

```
const setBlockedDate = useCallback(idx => ev => {
    setBlockedDates(bd => arraySplice(bd,idx,1,[ev.value]));
},[setBlockedDates])

...

{blockedDates.map((bd,idx) => <VehicleBlockedDate 
    key={bd[REACT_KEY]} 
    defaultValue={bd} 
    onChange={setBlockedDate(idx)} 
    onDelete={deleteBlockedDate(idx)} 
   reasons={[]}/>)}
```

`useCallback` will only memoize the outer function, but not the inner one. Is there a helper function for this pattern? Because I don't think this is right:

```
    const setBlockedDate = useCallback(idx => useCallback(ev => {
        setBlockedDates(bd => arraySplice(bd,idx,1,[ev.value]));
    },[setBlockedDates]),[setBlockedDates])
```

Comment: What if you move the `setBlockedDate` into the `VehicleBlockedDate`? Remove the `onChange` prop, but send the `idx` variable in. Inside you could then make wherever the `onChange` was used in `VehicleBlockedDate` a function created with `useCallback`. That should eliminate the need for the outer `useCallback`. (the same could be done with `deleteBlockedDate`.) Another idea would be to `useMemo` the result of `blockedDates.map` and render that result.

Comment: @simnys I could, but I don't want `<VehicleBlockedDate>` to concern itself with that sort of thing. It shouldn't care whether it was used in a loop or not.

Comment: what about doing `useMemo` on the mapped `blockedDates` then?

Comment: @simnys Throws an error when I add another `VehicleBlockedDate` item: " React has detected a change in the order of Hooks". I guess because I'm dynamically introducing a new `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is correct:

```
function useArrayCallback(fn, deps = []) {
    return useMemo(() => memoize(idx => (...args) => fn(idx, ...args)), deps);
}
```

Where `memoize` is:

```
function memoize(fn, options={
    serialize: fn.length === 1 ? x => x : (...args) => JSON.stringify(args),
}) {
    const cache = new Map();
    return (...args) => {
        const key = options.serialize(...args);
        if(cache.has(key)) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
        const value = fn(...args);
        cache.set(key, value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Or you can use some fancy-pants prebuilt memoize function.

Then the callback in the original question can be written as:

```js
const setBlockedDate = useArrayCallback((idx,ev) => {
    setBlockedDates(bd => arraySplice(bd,idx,1,[ev.value]));
})
```